# Why does "heroku console" with Padrino give useless error messages?

Tags: ruby, heroku, padrino

When using `heroku console`, I always get "Internal server error" when an exception is raised rather than a stacktrace as I would expect.

Here's a transcript of what I mean:

```
$ heroku console
Ruby console for myapp.heroku.com
>> var_that_does_not_exist
 !   Internal server error
>>
$ heroku run bundle exec padrino console -e production
Running bundle exec padrino console -e production attached to terminal... up, run.9
=> Loading production console (Padrino v.0.10.1)
=> Loading Application MyApp
=> Loading Application Admin
irb(main):001:0> var_that_does_not_exist
NameError: undefined local variable or method `var_that_does_not_exist' for main:Object
        from (irb):1
irb(main):002:0>
```

Any ideas on what I can change to get the stack traces?

Comment: Thats a good question, I tend to use the "heroku run bundle exec..." approach when I am running my Padrino apps on cedar stack. I'll check back here but if you figure it out maybe we can add it into one of the Padrino guides...

Comment: The "heroku run" solution seems to work just fine on the Bamboo stack also.  It seems that there should be a setting for whatever "heroku console" does that we can just change...  The solution will have to go in the guides, when we get it.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest version of the Heroku gem. Running `heroku update` should resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`heroku console` has been deprecated. You should use `heroku run …` instead. Depending on your rails version, one of the following should work:

$ heroku run script/console
$ heroku run bundle exec rails console

Comment: Or for Padrino (what we're using for the app in question):  `heroku run padrino console`.  That's definitely the way to go now, but at the time it was a Heroku bug (see accepted answer).